# Android: Slide View Upwards Anywhere Inside App

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, view

Within a new app that I am creating, I am building an achievements system. I failed to get Toast click actions to work, so I have decided that using another view might be a good idea (which I actually prefer).

The idea: I'd like a view to be accessible within all of my activities, that is hidden below the screen. When an achievement is "unlocked", the view slides up and says "Achievement Unlocked: ", then slides back down after *x* seconds.

How would I create this view, and how would I then add it to all of my activities to allow it to slide up at any time? I'd like to give it an ID also.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use one activity, and host other fragments in it. In this way, it would be easy to show/hide a fragment in `FrameLayout`. But considering that you want to show some kind of popup, with animation from bottom, in any `Activity`, I would create a new Activity, with animation_in (slide from bottom), and animation_out(slide out to bottom). Also if you want to set any part of the activity to be transparent, you can modify "popupActivity" theme by making it transparent. In such a way, you can show the popup from bottom in any activity.

---

Example:

1. Create `anim` folder inside `res` folder.
2. Create `slide_in_from_bottom_to_top.xml` inside `anim` and insert the following xml code:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set>
   <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromYDelta="100%"
       android:toYDelta="0"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
       android:duration="500"/>
   </set>
   ```
3. Create `slide_out_to_bottom_from_top.xml` inside `anim` folder:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <set>
   <translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:fromYDelta="0"
       android:toYDelta="100%"
       android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
       android:duration="500"/>
    </set>
   ```
4. To start Activity with animation, just `overridePendingTransition` inside `onCreate` method in `PopupActivity` as follows:

   ```
   overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom_to_top, R.anim.slide_out_to_bottom_from_top);
   ```

Send data to activity and retrieve it:

In your current Activity, create a new Intent:

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NewActivity.class);
i.putExtra("new_variable_name","value");
startActivity(i);
```

Then in the new Activity, retrieve those values:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("new_variable_name");
}
```

Use this technique to pass variables from one Activity to the other.

---

But considering that you don't need all of this, you could simply use `SnackBar`, an example can be here: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/

Comment: Could you make an example? I'm new to this. :/

Comment: How do I style that like I would do with any other view? See this: https://i.imgur.com/daWrYMR.png

Comment: That is a `SnackBar`, see how it works here: http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-snackbar-example/

Comment: But if you still want to do it in `PopupActivity`, just style activity to be transparent, then in activity layout set parent layout to be RelativeLayout, and alignParentBottom the view which pops up

Comment: @FlipLunch Thanks! That SnackBar thing seems like it could work. Change your answer to that and I'll mark it as solved.